# Smart deleteng cached of squid

Tags: squid

Is there a way to auto delete cached of squid when a the client closes the browser? A cached must be related to the client of course.

Or is squid capable of detecting a client if a client closes the browser?

Answer (score 0):

No, squid's cache is independent of any clients that might connect to it. Squid cannot detect client application activity such as closing a browser window.